# ROR: Routes issue - Survey gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Survey gem is not creating the routes on my Rails app so I am wondering what to put in the routes.rb file?

I ran

```
 rails generate survey:install
```

then ran

```
rails generate survey routes namespace:survey
```

and does not work.

I'm using Rails 4.2.1

The controllers are at controllers/survey/attempts_controller.rb and controllers/survey/surveys_controller.rb

The views are at survey/attempts/ and survey/surveys/

How should I put in the routes for these? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay if it didn't add routes to your `routes.rb` file. You can add it yourself. And since you have it namespaced within `Survey` for your controllers you have to namespace in your routes file too.

```
namespace :survey do
  resources :surveys
  resources :attempts
  get 'survey_details' => 'surveys#get_details' #this request will be handled by get_details method of SurveysController
end
```

Since it uses basic Create Read Update Delete in its controller, `resources :surveys` will take care of these. For any additional routes you want to define for your controllers make sure to put them inside the `namespace` block.

Comment: Thanks both, this fixed it, more specifically Kumar's answer but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Survey uses a standard CRUD interface, so you should be able to add resources named after the survey model you've created.

i.e. `resources :surveys`

If this doesn't do the trick, you can see a basic routing setup in the survey demo app here: https://github.com/runtimerevolution/survey-demo/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Let me know if this helps!